# give an array a-z until possibly ZZZ... key with php or python

Tags: php, python, logic

Let's say i have an unknown string in an array, it will look like

```
$arr = array(
'string 1',
'string 2',
'string 3',
'string 4',
'string 5',
// up to a certain unknown amount
```

**1. How can we give them a value like below?**

```
'string 1' => a, 
'string 2' => b,
'string 26' => z, 
'string 27' => A,
'string 52' => Z,
'string 53' => aa,
// up to a certain unknown amount possibly until ZZZZ, or maybe more.
```

update heres what ive done so far

```
function num2a($a){

    # A-Z
    for ($i=65; $i < 91 ; $i++) { 
        #echo chr($i);
        $arr[] = chr($i);
    }

    # a-z
    for ($i=97; $i < 123 ; $i++) { 
        #echo chr($i);
        $arr[] = chr($i);
    }

    // a-Z
    if ( 0 <= $a && $a <= 51 ) {
        echo $arr[$a];
    }

    // aa-ZZ not done
    if ( 52 <= $a && $a <= 53 ) {

        for ($x=0; $x < 1; $x++) {
            # A = 0  
            # a = 26
            # somehow if i put $a = 52 it will do a aa
            $a = $a - 26;
            $arr[$a] = $arr[$a] . $arr[$a];
            echo $arr[$a];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you have an infinite array?

Comment: The answer is yes you can generate those values for your strings, and yes you can remove the duplicate keys. Were you hoping for more? Yes to that too? Then show us what you've written. It's like you're giving the world a homework assignment.

Comment: You could try something with [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and an auto-generated array. For the second problem I'd suggest using [array_uniqye](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: @Dan and webarto said everything, there's no research effort, progress or real problem in this question, just using SO as Google.

Comment: Generally if your input domain is infinite, you write a function to dynamically calculate the outputs. Computers scientists haven't yet determined how to store infinite data.

Comment: Also: 125 questions and 6 answers? I mean... just wow.

Comment: really, its not about the infinite data, we just don't know how long it could be, and im not giving a world a home work assignment, im just asking for where to start. thanks!

Comment: @M_rk thats what im looking for, great. ill try to give updates.

Comment: I think you should move the 2nd part of the question out, removing duplicates is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Python it's relatively easy to have an infinite array using generators, as well as arbitrarily long ones, lazily evaluated ones, etc.  What you'd want to do to map this kind of thing to keys is to have an infinitely long, lazily evaluated list, or *generator*.

```
import itertools
import string
```

First you want itertools, which has lots of handy functions for manipulating infinite size arrays.  string includes some standard string constants.

```
def lower_then_upper():
    return iter(string.letters)
```

`iter` here isn't strictly required, but it will turn the standard list into a generator, for consistency.

```
def get_n(n=2):
    generators = []
    for gen in range(n):
        generators.append(lower_then_upper())
    tuples = itertools.product(*generators)
    return itertools.imap(''.join, tuples)
```

Here we start putting things together, this function will return the list of strings of a fixed length made of up the letters.  Line by line, the bits before `tuples` ensures that there is a generator for all strings available for each letter position.  i.e. three  a-Z lists would be created if n=3.

Below, `itertools.product` does a cartesian product of all the things available, which in Python luckily iterates the last first, so you get for n=2: `` `['aa', 'ab', ..., 'ZX', 'ZY', 'ZZ'] ``.

The final line, `itertools.imap` applies the function `''.join` to every item in tuples.  Until now they were of the form `(('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), …`, this ensures they are a string, in the same way that `''.join(['a', 'a']) == 'aa'`.

```
def get_infinite():
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        for item in get_n(n):
            yield item
```

Here is where the magic happens.  It will exhaust the iterator for n=1 before going on to exhaust n=2, and so on.

```
def inf_hello():
    while True:
        yield "hello world"
```

This is just a demo infinite list

```
mapped = itertools.izip(get_infinite(), inf_hello())
```

Now, we zip them together to get an infinite array of key/value pairs:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(mapped, 1000, 1010))
[('sm', 'hello world'), ('sn', 'hello world'), ('so', 'hello world'), ('sp', 'hello world'), ('sq', 'hello world'), ('sr', 'hello world'), ('ss', 'hello world'), ('st', 'hello world'), ('su', 'hello world'), ('sv', 'hello world')]
```

as we can see if we introspect it 1000 elements in.

Alternatively, we can give it a long list and get a dictionary:

```
>>> numbers = dict(itertools.izip(get_infinite(), range(0, 10000)))
>>> print numbers['a'], numbers['aa'], numbers['caW']
0 52 8212
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Warning, in psuedo-code. This is an idea, first create a map like so

```
map['1'->'26'] = 'a'->'z'
map['27'->'52'] = 'A'->'Z'
```

Now from the list of data all you need is the number. You can use the number to get appropriate values like so,

```
int numFromData = getNumber('string 53')
while( numFromData > 0){
   int mapKey = numFromData % 52; //since we have 52 mapped values
   print( map[ mapKey] ); 
   numFromData /= 52; 
}
```

I think that should work, no guarantees, but the idea is correct.

Comment: sometimes you will use map[0]

Comment: yea I know, was trying to make the algorithm simple, without worrying about map[0], just to get the idea across

Answer (score 0):

Well you can give it numeric keys easily:

```
$strArray = explode(",",$string);
```

Comment: @webarto the OP said string, not array

Comment: I quoted you that part, check his question again, it is array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = ""; // Your String
$results = array();
$input = explode(",", $str);
foreach($input as $v) {
    $value = explode("=>", $v);
    if(!isset($results[$value[0]])) {
        $results[$value[0]] = $value[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you don't really need upper case

```
for($i="a";$i!="bc";++$i)
    print $i."\n";
```